# How to split a multipage pdf into multiple pdf files in Flutter

Tags: flutter, pdf

Is there a way to split a pdf document into several pdfs in flutter (Windows)? I've tried with pdf and syncfussion flutter pdf and i haven't found a way yet.

Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to use a MultiPage

```
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;
.
.
.
pdf.addPage(
    pw.MultiPage(
      pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
      orientation: pw.PageOrientation.portrait,
      build: (pw.Context context) {
        return [
          pw.Column(
.
.
.
//Then if you want to List Items from a List it is better to use a for loop
for (int i = 0;i < products.length; i++){
//display widgets
}
 //using a ListView may result in height greater than a pdf sheet giving an error
```